# Get operations list from interface ID in ZeroC Ice

Tags: ice

[Dynamic Ice](http://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice/Dynamic+Ice) manual section doesn't explain how to obtain a list of operations (their names, argument and result types) implemented by an object, which seems to be pretty much necessary to "create applications such as object browsers, protocol analyzers". Is it possible? I am thinking of a case where a client doesn't have access to all Slice interfaces known to the server (e.g. because new ones can be loaded dynamically) and so wants to learn about them at the runtime. Is there any built-in way to do this in Ice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ice doesn't provide any introspection along the lines of the CORBA interface repository. You can create requests dynamically (without using compiled stubs), and you can respond to them dynamically (without using compiled skeletons) but, if you need to find out what types are involved, you have to get this knowledge from somewhere else.

Michi.